# Shouldn't I be able to use an Integer[] array in a switch statement?

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, switch-statement

I thought `Integer[]` arrays are fine to use in a `switch` statement, due to auto-boxing, where the `Integer` object and `int` primitive are exchanged back and forth automatically by the compiler. But I am not having luck putting my `Integer[]` items into a switch statement for an `OnClick` event. When the user clicks an image in my array, I want it to open in a new activity. What am I doing wrong? Getting red errors on my code, in both the `case` numbers and the `startActivity(i)` so it's definitely not right. Thanks.

**GridViewSitesAdapter.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutelinks;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.azurespot.R;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/11/15.
 */
public class GridViewSitesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public Context mContext;

    public GridViewSitesAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = new Integer[]{
            R.drawable.cute_overload, R.drawable.attack_of_the_cute,
            R.drawable.zoo_borns, R.drawable.cutest_paw,
            R.drawable.mochimochiland, R.drawable.baby_mugging,
            R.drawable.cutest_food, R.drawable.tiny_cute_things,
            R.drawable.etsy_robot_plush,
            R.drawable.fuck_yeah_fruits,
            R.drawable.ark_in_space,
            R.drawable.we_heart_it
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams
                (270,270));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gridview_image_border);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (mThumbIds){
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, CuteOverloadActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 1:

            }

                }
            }
        });
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can use an element of the array like `mThumbIds[0]`, but not the array as a whole.

Comment: I tried that in a case, putting it like `mThumbIds[0]` but it gave me an error saying `Required Integer[], found Integer`.

Comment: Why are you switching on `mThumbIds`? Shouldn't you be switching on `position`?

Comment: It says my `position` needs to be declared as `final`. Is that okay to add that?

Comment: Ahh... it worked @ianhanniballake. I tried changing it to `getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` and using `case 0`, `case 1`, etc. with `switch(position)` and it worked, thanks! If you want to rewrite that in an answer I will mark as correct. :)

Comment: @NoniA.: Becuase `mThumbIds` array contains ids like 238333,3232933,...  any id generated by system at so if you pass `mThumbIds[0]` in switch case then you should use 238333,3232933,... id's with cases. my suggestion is just use `position` see my answer will help

Comment: Unrelated to this question but if you find your grid view scrolls slowly or stutters, look up view recycling and view holders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your switch statement shouldn't be on `mThumbIds` but on `position` (as it is the position of the element which determines what to do). Note you'll need to declare `position` as `final` to access it within the `onClick` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTag/getTag` method to get actual position of clicked row:

```
    imageView.setTag(position);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                 int clickedPos=Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                    switch (clickedPos){
                    case 0:
                      ....
                }
          }
   }
 });
```

Comment: This would be required if he only called `setOnClickListener` if `convertView == null` (i.e., when building a new view). In this case he's setting the `OnClickListener` each and every time `getView()` is called meaning he'll always have the latest `position`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: your solution cause issue when ListView has scrollable items

Comment: In this case, he's throwing out the entire view rather than reusing the view (incorrectly, if he wanted any good performance) so he dodges any issue with reusing views.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: if getView method called 10 times. when we click on 2nd row of ListView then position value will be 10 on ImageView click which is last value assigned in `position` with last call of getView method? correct me if im wrong

Comment: @ianhanniballake: anyway your solution fix OP issue but i 'm still not sure OP will get right  row clicked position using your answer. Thanks have a nice day:)

Comment: That is incorrect. Due to the `final` keyword, each `OnClickListener` will get a copy of `position` at its correct value when the object is created not just the last `position` to come through `getView`. Answers on 'java final inner class' can provide more details.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: wrong. for example `for(int i=0,i<=5;i++){final int pos=i; new dummyMethod(post)} int pos=0; public void dummyMethod(final int pos){this.pos=pos}`   Now on Button  click if we print `pos` then what value is printed ?? accoding to me `5`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70897/discussion-between-ianhanniballake-and--k).